# Rails integration test: my test posts a new entry to the controller, how do I retrieve this entry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, minitest, fixtures

I am having a problem knowing how to retrieve the new entry my test just posted.
Here's my code:

```
post admin_bundles_path, params: { bundle: {
    title: "New bundle",
    sku: "ASD-FESTA-00001-XM",
} }, xhr: true
assert_response :ok
```

So far, so good. Now, how do I check the attributes of this new entry? The older entries are on my fixtures, so I can access them by `bundles(:some_bundle)`, for example. How do I do it for the new one?

Comment: If you are not familiar with `byebug` gem, I would highly recommend using it. It is simple to use and will solve this and many many other debug issues. Let me know if you need to know more about it, I will post that as an answer or you can read about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Bundle.last
```

Which will get the last entry which you have just posted. Be warned! If for some reason your post request fails, then you will actually be retrieving the older entries in your fixtures.

If you want to be absolutely sure, then you can do something like this:

```
Bundle.where(title: "New bundle", sku: "ASD-FESTA-00001-XM").first
```

That will produce an error, if for some reason the post request fails.

Comment: Thanks, BK, it worked! I, being a dumb dumb, didn't realize you could access it through the DB. That's a junior dev for you, I guess.

Comment: @vmfrcosta dude you're waaaay too harsh on yourself, you're testing, and you're asking questions,  which are great...... and you're learning. You could very well be writing some core rails commits before too long!!